# catch enter in ms-access and treeview

Tags: ms-access, vba, treeview

I'm trying to catch [ENTER] in a Microsoft TreeView-control.

this code runs fine on any ordinary key, but not enter.

```
Private Sub xProductTreeview_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  'do something treeview can understand..
  Application.Quit
End Sub
```

now keypress doesn't trigger on ENTER, so trying KeyDown,
with help from http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/here-syntax-treeview-keydown-t3810664.html
the official declaration is incorrect and the following code works:

```
Private Sub xProductTreeview_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer)
  'do something treeview can understand..
  If KeyCode = 32 Then Application.Quit
  'Still, KeyCode=13 doesn't trigger nothing..
End Sub
```

Tried with setting KeyPreivew in access-form to true.

EDIT:
This actually works..

setting KeyPreview to true and:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
  If KeyCode = 13 Then MsgBox xProductTreeview.SelectedItem.Text
End Sub
```

The only thing left so sort out is the returned value is the label-value, which may be non-unique, so how do I get the Key instead of the Text of the node??

regards,
//t

Comment: ah, it works, then:
Dim nodSelected As MSComctlLib.Node    
Set nodSelected = Me.xProductTreeview.SelectedItem
MsgBox nodSelected.Key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keyPreview=true and

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
  If KeyCode = 13 Then
    Dim nodSelected As MSComctlLib.Node
    Set nodSelected = Me.xProductTreeview.SelectedItem
    MsgBox nodSelected.Key
  end if
End Sub
```